# If $f=g$ almost everywhere then which implication is TRUE?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

> Let , $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a given function. Consider the following statements :
>
> **A .** The function $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.
>
> **B .** There exists a continuous function $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f=g$ almost everywhere.
>
> Which of the following implications are TRUE ?
>
> **1 .** $A\implies B$.
>
> **2 .** $B\implies A$.
>
> **3 .** $A\iff B$.

Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0 &\text{ if }x=0\text{ or }x\text{ is irrational}\\\frac{1}{q}&\text{ if }x=\frac{p}{q},\text{ where }gcd(p,q)=1\end{cases}$$Then , $f$ is discontinuous in $\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}$ , and $m\left(\mathbb Q\setminus \{0\}\right)=0$. So , $f$ is continuous almost everywhere.

Consider , $g(x)\equiv0$. So , $f=g$ almost everywhere. Thus , **1 .** is TRUE.

---

Again , consider $g\equiv 0$ , which is continuous. Consider , $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1 &\text{, if }x\in \mathbb Q\\0&\text{ , if }x\in \mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q\end{cases}$$Then , $f=g$ almost everywhere , but $f$ is NOT continuous. Thus **2 .** is FALSE and so **3 .** is FALSE.

Am I correct or wrong ? If wrong where my fallacy ?

Comment: You can't prove that 1. is true with an example. You can prove that any of them (such as 2. and 3.) are *false* by giving *counterexamples*, as you did. But 1. is a statement about *all* functions $f$, not just the one you exhibit.

Comment: Well...So how we can prove or disprove 1 ?

Comment: Consider a function f(x) = -1 if x<0 , f(x) = 1 if x>=0.  So this is continuous ae, but there is no function g which is continuous on all of R, there's always going to be a discontinuity at x=0.

Comment: A counterexample for 1.: Consider $f(x) = \frac 1 {x - \lfloor x \rfloor}$ for $x\notin \Bbb Z$, and $f(n) = 1$ for $n\in \Bbb Z$. $f$ is discontinuous (on the right) at every integer, where it blows up. The discontinuities are essential, they can't be removed.

Comment: if g=f almost everywhere, then f would be continuous where f=g, and discontinuous where f != g so B=>A . You should be able to prove this by the episilon/delta argument, or through use of sequences {x_i} converging to x where x is a point of agreement/point of disagreement of f and g - show that g(x_i)-->g(x) = f(x) and g(x_i)-->g(x) but f(x_i) doesn't converge to f(x) (but to g(x)) respectively.

Comment: A counterexample for 1.: Consider $f(x)=\frac 1 {x−\lfloor x \rfloor$ for $x\notin \Bbb N$, and $f(x)=1 for x\in \Bbb N or x<0$. $f$ is discontinuous (on the right) at every integer, where it blows up. The discontinuities are essential, they can't be removed.